# post increment or decrement operator as while condition

Tags: java

Here is the program

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 9; 
    while(y--){
        x++;
    } 
    System.out.println("x="+ x +"y=" +y);
}
```

I am getting compilation error why?.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: @shmosel - Actually, no.  The problem is that `while` requires a `boolean` and `y--` isn't.

Comment: abdulsafuwan - next time, be sure to include the compilation error **messages** that you are asking about.

Comment: @StephenC you should post that as an answer.  seems legit to me.

Comment: My feeling is that this Q is too low quality for a proper answer.  For example, it (still) doesn't have the compilation errors, and the title is inaccurate.  And other things.  The OP has gotten the solution to his problem ... so he should be satisfied.  The point of writing quality answers is that they will / should help other people than the OP.  But if the question is such that other people are unlikely to find it in a search, the effort will be largely wasted.

Answer (score 2):

In this programme the argument of the while loop is incorrect. Because int cannot be converted to boolean. Because of that you must change the argument like while(y--!=0) or something like that.If you want print all the list you must change the position of print statement like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 9;
    while(y--!=0){
        x++;
        System.out.println("x="+x +"and y=" +y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting error as : **int cannot be converted to boolean
while(y--){**
If you try to compare y-- inside while like :
while(y-- != 0) then it will be fine or add any other condition you want.